# IE issue with :visible?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, cross-browser

Can anyone tell me how to make this work in IE? It works perfectly in every other browser!

I'm assuming the `:visible` is the problem?

TIA

```
$('.yes').click(function () {
    $('.question:visible')
        .fadeOut()
        .closest('.question')
        .nextAll('.question')
        .eq(0)
        .delay(400)
        .fadeIn();
});
```

All questions are in this format:

```
<div class="question">
<p>Question 1</p>
<h1>is this a question?</h1>
<label class="btn"><input type="radio" name="question1" value="yes"><span class="yes">YES</span></label>
<label class="btn"><input type="radio" name="question1" value="no"><span class="no">NO</span></label>
<label class="btn"><input type="radio" name="question1" value="maybe"><span class="maybe">MAYBE</span></label>
</div>
```

Question >1 looks like this:

```
<div class="hiddenquestion">
<p>Question 2</p>
<h1>is this a question?</h1>
<label class="btn"><input type="radio" name="question2" value="yes"><span class="yes">YES</span></lable>
<label class="btn"><input type="radio" name="question2" value="no"><span class="no">NO</span></lable>
<label class="btn"><input type="radio" name="question2" value="maybe"><span class="maybe">MAYBE</span></lable>
</div>
```

where .hiddenquestion is of-course display: none;

Comment: What does your HTML look like?

Comment: IE 9, haven't tested <9 yet, html added. Thanks in advance

Comment: I understand what closest does, i have 10 questions, answering the question fades out the :visible one and fades in the next. It works perfectly in every other browser except IE, thanks for your input.

Comment: whats does `$('.yes').click(function () { alert($('.question:visible').length); });` tell you?

Comment: @undefined don't forget `closest` tests the element itself as well as the parents

Comment: @Danny can you just confirm what you're expecting to happen? Are you expecting the next question to show when *yes* is clicked?

Comment: @ChrisMoutray alert displays 1 in IE and other browsers.

Comment: @ChrisMoutray, i explained the logic above - "i have 10 questions, answering the question fades out the :visible one and fades in the next."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok so there's a couple of problems here

First, your label tags are not closing correctly as someone has already commented `</lable>` should be `</label>`.

Second, from your example your hidden questions have the class attribute set like this `<div class="hiddenquestion">` but i suspect there should be a space in there meaning this is what you wanted `<div class="hidden question">`. You should have a css `.hidden { display: none; }` and not .hiddenquestion

Third, you need to add a click handler to the radio button as well as the tag (or at this this is the only way it seems to work in IE) in which case your js should look something like this.

```
var fn = function () {
    $('.question:visible')
        .fadeOut()
        .closest('.question')
        .nextAll('.question')
        .eq(0)
        .delay(400)
        .fadeIn();
};

// click handler on the yes label
$('.yes').click(fn);

// click handler on the actual yes radio
$(':radio[value="yes"]').change(fn);
```

Comment: Perfect, thank you, it's now working great in IE 8 & 9

Comment: @Danny Ok but without the 2nd point I'm not sure your code would work since in your examples hidden questions have the class 'hiddenquestion' (no spaces) - so I'm not sure how the code `.nextAll('.question')` would work... Anyway if you have it working then that's not a problem...

Comment: Bizzare, it was working ok so i guess the fadeIn canceled out the display:none? Although i'm using display: block on Q1 and .question display:none now which is also working great. Anyway, all good now so thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem is this

```
<label class="btn"><input type="radio" name="question2" value="yes"><span class="yes">YES</span></lable>
```

Notice the invalid closing tag for `<label>`, `</lable>`. This renders the markup invalid in IE.

### Update:

Tested in IE9/8 with following, works fine

#### Markup

```
<button class="yes">YESS!</button>
  <div class="question" style="display: block">
     <p>Question 1</p>
     <h1>is this a question?</h1>
     <label class="btn">
        <input type="radio" name="question1" value="yes" />
        <span class="yes">YES</span>
     </label> <label class="btn">
        <input type="radio" name="question1" value="no">
        <span class="no">NO</span></label> <label class="btn">
        <input type="radio" name="question1" value="maybe">
        <span class="maybe">MAYBE</span></label>
  </div>
<div class="question">
     <p>Question 2</p>
     <h1>is this a question?</h1>
     <label class="btn">
        <input type="radio" name="question1" value="yes" />
        <span class="yes">YES</span>
     </label> <label class="btn">
        <input type="radio" name="question1" value="no">
        <span class="no">NO</span></label> <label class="btn">
        <input type="radio" name="question1" value="maybe">
        <span class="maybe">MAYBE</span></label>
  </div>
<div class="question">
     <p>Question 3</p>
     <h1>is this a question?</h1>
     <label class="btn">
        <input type="radio" name="question1" value="yes" />
        <span class="yes">YES</span>
     </label> <label class="btn">
        <input type="radio" name="question1" value="no">
        <span class="no">NO</span></label> <label class="btn">
        <input type="radio" name="question1" value="maybe">
        <span class="maybe">MAYBE</span></label>
  </div>
```

#### CSS

```
.question{display: none;}
```

### Update

In order to make it work on click of the radio button *or* the label text in all browsers, you'll have to change your javascript to

```
//change the selector of .yes to
$('label.yes').click(function () {...
```

And change the markup of "yes" section of the question to

```
<label class="btn yes">
    <input type="radio" name="question1" value="yes" />
    <span>YES</span>
</label>
```

Comment: Then you must be wanting something other than _hiding the current visible question on click of `.yes` button, and displaying the next hidden question_

Comment: I just tried this, and i still get nothing after clicking an answer?

Comment: BTW are you sure you're clicking on the "yes" _text_ and not the radio button. If you want to fade it out on click of the radio button of the text 'Yes' then you'll have to put the "yes" class on the label. Check update momentarily

Comment: To clarify all i changed from my original markup was added display: block to question 1 and added .question {display: none} to my css

Comment: please look at my original markup more closely, the class exists on the radio button, as i said it works great on every other browser.

Comment: Actually, in browsers other than IE, does it hide the question upon clicking on the yes _radio button_ ? It doesn't for me.

Comment: Yes Danny, sorry i didn't observe the class on the span element before

Comment: No worries, +1 for the closing label tag, appreciate the help.